# How do I get a number of days left if the number of days includes the days of another year?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, date-difference

I am trying to implement something that can countdown how many days left before an event occurs. While dealing with days within the same year is fine. But now I am having a problem with showing a number of days which includes days that are not in the current year. For instance, if I input the target date as 1 January 2020 and current date as 30 September 2019. It will return -272 (days) which does not make any sense in general.

I have tried understanding and using code online but none of them worked for me.

What the code below does is to return a number of days left but only work when the days are within the same year. The labeledDate variable is a part of an inputted string (dateStamp) that shows only date that has the format of "dd MMMM yyyy".

```
// Show how many days left before event occurs
        try {
            String labeledDate = viewHolder.dateStamp.getText().toString().substring(5);

            Calendar currentDay = Calendar.getInstance();
            final Calendar targetDay = Calendar.getInstance();

            SimpleDateFormat ourDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            targetDay.setTime(ourDateFormat.parse(labeledDate));

            if (targetDay.compareTo(currentDay) > 0) {

                int daysLeft = targetDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - currentDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

                if (daysLeft == 1) {
                    viewHolder.dayCounter.setText("Tomorrow");
                }
                else {
                    viewHolder.dayCounter.setText(daysLeft + " days");
                }
            }
            else if (targetDay.compareTo(currentDay) == 0) {
                viewHolder.dayCounter.setText("Today");
            }
            else {
                viewHolder.dayCounter.setText("Expired");
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.d("PARSE EXCEPTION", e.getMessage());
        }
```

According to my current understanding of Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR is that it consists of (maybe) 365 days. And if I enter the date 1st January 2020, it won't listen to the year whereas it will just focus on the day and month. Hence, if I entered the target date as 1st January 2020 and current date as 30th September 2019, then it would return -272 (days) from the day on 1st January minus the day on 30th September (years ignored).

What I want is that if I enter the inputs above then it will return 93 days instead of -272 days. Anything that can help me achieve this is appreciated.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You logic is working for same year just because `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)` returns day count from 1 Jan to given date for the year. So in case of same year, target-date and current-date are working as expected. Lets explore it by an example

```
targetCalendar.set(2019, 11, 31);

System.out.println(currentCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)); // Day of year since 1 Jan 2019, which is 273
System.out.println(targetCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));  // Day of year since 1 Jan 2019, which is 365
// So your logic as per question works fine, gives 92 days (365 - 273) as result for below
System.out.println(targetCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - currentCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));


// No lets change date for targetCalendar into next year
targetCalendar.set(2020, 0, 1);

System.out.println(currentCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)); // Day of year since 1 Jan 2019, which is 273
System.out.println(targetCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));  // Day of year since 1 Jan 2020, which is 1
// So your logic as per question works fine, gives -272 days (1 - 273) as result for below
System.out.println(targetCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - currentCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
```

Hope you got the problem in your logic.

---

You can get result by doing like

```
long msDiff = targetDay.getTimeInMillis() - currentDay.getTimeInMillis();
long daysDiff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(msDiff);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I always get the days difference:

```
String cDate = "09/30/2019";
String fDate = "09/30/2020";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date currentDate = df.parse(cDate);
Date futureDate = df.parse(fDate);

long diffMill = Math.abs(currentDate.getTime() - futureDate.getTime());
long diff = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffMill, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

With java.time, the modern Java date and time API, it’s simpler:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

    String labeledDate = "01 January 2020";
    LocalDate currentDay = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/Louisville"));
    try {
        LocalDate targetDay = LocalDate.parse(labeledDate, dateFormatter);
        long daysLeft = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(currentDay, targetDay);
        if (daysLeft < 0) {
            System.out.println("Expired");
        } else if (daysLeft == 0) {
            System.out.println("Today");
        } else if (daysLeft == 1) {
            System.out.println("Tomorrow");
        } else {
            System.out.println("" + daysLeft + " days");
        }
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        System.out.println("Parse exception: " + dtpe.getMessage());
    }
```

When I ran this code snippet just now, the output was:

> 92 days

Please substitute your desired time zone if it didn’t happen to be America/Louisville. Because it is never the same date in all places on Earth.

If you don’t want to base the if-else construct on the number of days left alone, you may also use the `isEqual`, `isBefore` and/or `isAfter` method of `LocalDate`.

### But doesn’t it require Android API level 26?

It doesn’t require API level 26. java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.